# Given points $A(7,2)$, $B(-4,2)$, $P(x,2x)$ such that the distance from $A$ to $P$ is equal to the distance from $B$ to $P$, find $x$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have $A(7,2)$ and $B(-4,2)$, these 2 points in my graph.

I have another point $P(x,2x)$.

The distance between points $A$ and $P$ is equal to the distance between points $B$ and $P$.

Find $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.  You will need to translate the problem into an equation involving $x$.

Comment: Do you know the Pythagorean theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the distance between two points in a plane. If we have the points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$, then the distance between them if defined by:
$$d(A,B) = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$$
In this problem we are said that the distance between $A$ and $P$ is the same as the distance between $B$ and $P$, so applying the definition and equaling we get
$$\sqrt{(7- x)^2 + (2 - 2x)^2} = \sqrt{(-4 - x)^2 + (2 - 2x)^2}$$
Square both sides, calcel the second sumand of each side and  appling the square identity for subtraction:
$$49 - 14x + x^2 = 16 + 8x + x^2$$
And solving this first degree equation (notice quatratic terms cancel each other out) we get:
$$x = \frac32$$